# JOIN table with subselect using Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to `JOIN` a subselect with another table in Laravel 5 Query Builder?

I mean - theoretically - something like this:

```
$sub = DB::table('A')->select(DB::Raw('id, MAX(date)'))->groupBy('id')->get();

$query = DB::table('B')->join($sub, 'B.id', '=', $sub->id)->get();
```

In my case, in table **A** I have duplicated rows. I need the ones with max `date` per `id`. Then I need to join the result with table **B**.

Comment: Post your solution as an acceptable answer. This will help people looking for a similar solution, also, this can help you being awarded the `self-learner` badge.

Comment: Yeah, I will probably do it later during the day, although this is not a real solution to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

As adviced in comments, a workaround follows.

```
$idArray= DB::table('A')->select(DB::Raw('id, MAX(date)'))->groupBy('id')->lists('id');

$query = DB::table('B')->whereIn('id', $idArray)->get();
```

But, again, just a workaround.